# Fill value of selector field into another field in Acumatica ERP System

Tags: c#, acumatica

I already create new custom field for screen Fixed Asset. The following code is my DAC extension:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR; 
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.FA;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace SGLCustomizeProject
{
    public class FALocationHistoryExtension : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.FA.FALocationHistory>
    {
        #region UsrKodeArea
        [PXDBString(50)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Kode Area")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<KodeAreaMaster.roomCD, 
                        Where<KodeAreaMaster.status, 
                        Equal<statusActive>, 
                        And<KodeAreaMaster.buildingID, 
                        Equal<Current<FALocationHistory.buildingID>>>>>),
                typeof(KodeAreaMaster.roomCD), 
                typeof(KodeAreaMaster.roomDescription),
                typeof(KodeAreaMaster.buildingID),
                typeof(KodeAreaMaster.status))]
        public virtual string UsrKodeArea { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrKodeArea : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrDeskripsiArea
        [PXDBString(75)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Deskripsi Area")]
        public virtual string UsrDeskripsiArea { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrDeskripsiArea : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I need to fill the selected value into another additional field in the current screen, please see the following screenshot:

[image]

I need to fill value of Deskripsi Area from selector field (pop up) into Deskripsi Area field.

I have tried the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.FA.Overrides.AssetProcess;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.FA;

namespace SGLCustomizeProject
{
    public class AssetMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<AssetMaint>
    {
        public virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<FALocationHistory, FALocationHistoryExtension.usrKodeArea> e)
        {
            var row = e.Row;
            var ext = row.GetExtension<FALocationHistoryExtension>();
            e.Cache.SetValue<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrDeskripsiArea>(row, ext.UsrKodeArea);
        }
    }
}
```

This code above has been worked, but the result is when I choose Kode Area field, it also fill into Deskripsi Area field. My goal is to fill Deskripsi Area with the same field (Deskripsi Area) from selector field.

[image]

I tried to change code above with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.FA.Overrides.AssetProcess;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.FA;

namespace SGLCustomizeProject
{
    public class AssetMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<AssetMaint>
    {
        public virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<FALocationHistory, FALocationHistoryExtension.usrKodeArea> e)
        {
            var row = e.Row;
            var ext = row.GetExtension<FALocationHistoryExtension>();
            e.Cache.SetValue<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrDeskripsiArea>(row, ext.UsrDeskripsiArea);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any step that I forget ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57053685/7198805

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've tried your suggestion by used link above, but I still got error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to provide my goal. Thanks for everyone for all the respons. :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.FA.Overrides.AssetProcess;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.FA;


namespace SGLCustomizeProject
{
    public class AssetMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<AssetMaint>
    {
        public virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<FALocationHistory, FALocationHistoryExtension.usrKodeArea> e)
        {
            var row = e.Row;
            var ext = row.GetExtension<FALocationHistoryExtension>();
            if (ext.UsrKodeArea != null)
            {
                e.Cache.SetValue<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrDeskripsiArea>(row, ext.UsrKodeArea);
                var kodeAreaMaster = PXSelect<KodeAreaMaster,
                                 Where<KodeAreaMaster.roomCD,
                                 Equal<Required<KodeAreaMaster.roomCD>>>>
                                 .Select(Base, ext.UsrKodeArea).First().GetItem<KodeAreaMaster>();
                e.Cache.SetValueExt<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrDeskripsiArea>(row, kodeAreaMaster.RoomDescription);
            }
        }

        public virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<FALocationHistory.buildingID> e)
        {
            var row = e.Row as FALocationHistory;
            var ext = row.GetExtension<FALocationHistoryExtension>();

            if (row.BuildingID != null)
            {
                if (ext.UsrKodeArea != null)
                {
                    var kodeAreaMaster = PXSelect<KodeAreaMaster,
                                 Where<KodeAreaMaster.roomCD,
                                 Equal<Required<KodeAreaMaster.roomCD>>>>
                                 .Select(Base, ext.UsrKodeArea).First().GetItem<KodeAreaMaster>();
                    if (row.BuildingID == kodeAreaMaster.BuildingID)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         e.Cache.SetValueExt<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrKodeArea>(row, null);
                        e.Cache.SetValueExt<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrDeskripsiArea>(row, null);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cache.SetValueExt<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrKodeArea>(row, null);
                e.Cache.SetValueExt<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrDeskripsiArea>(row, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. use xxx_fieldUpdated event
2. In your aspx page check, that you have commitchanges set to true
3. [ as usually optional ] sometime is necessary to set autorefresh = true

Starting from 2017 R2 you can also use this approach:

```
    public virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<FALocationHistory, FALocationHistoryExtension.usrKodeArea> e)
    {
        var row = e.Row;
        var ext = row.GetExtension<FALocationHistoryExtension>();
        e.Cache.SetValue<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrDeskripsiArea>(row, ext.UsrKodeArea);
        var KodeAreaMaster =
            PXSelect<KodeAreaMaster, Where<KodeAreaMaster.roomCD, Equal<Required<KodeAreaMaster.roomCD>>>>
                .Select(Base, ext.UsrKodeArea).First().GetItem<KodeAreaMaster>();
        e.Cache.SetValueExt<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrDeskripsiArea>();

    }
```

Comment: I already follow your suggestions, but I still got error. Please see my updated code above. Thanks.

Comment: try this approach

Comment: I already follow your suggestion, please see my updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you speak about additional assignment. Additional assignment can be achieved with reading from database and assigning value over e.Cache.SetValueExt

Comment: I've made sample of changes, but for further improvements create new question

Comment: Thanks for your reference code, I've updated my code based on your suggestion and use some improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `ALocationHistoryExtension_UsrKodeArea_FieldUpdated` to `ALocationHistory_UsrKodeArea_FieldUpdated`

```
protected virtual void FALocationHistory_UsrKodeArea_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row is FALocationHistory)
        {
            sender.SetDefaultExt<FALocationHistoryExtension.usrDeskripsiArea>(e.Row);
        }
    }
```

[To Override an Event Handler](https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(2))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=4a05d4c2-cd8b-4131-bf3b-d05861de3ae6)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried your suggestion, the error message wa dissapear but it doesn't work.

Comment: In your aspx page check, that you have commit changes set to true for the `UsrKodeArea` field

Comment: I've set CommitChanges=true for the UsrKodeArea field.